What are the Mizar tools mizf and miz2prel?
You can build various executables that are distributed as part of the Mizar system with the following shell script adapted from this script from Roland Coghetto referred to in this answer by Alex Nelson to a question that I asked last week.
#!/bin/bash

die() {
        printf '%s\n' "$@" 1>&2
        exit 1
}

mkdir -p workdir bin || die "make dirs $?"

for d in ./*/*.dpr; do
        fpc -Fuaddtools -Fubase -Fukernel -Fulibtools -Fuusrtools -Mdelphi -FEbin "$d" || die "fpc $d $?"
done

mv ./bin/*.* ./workdir || die "move work files $?"

It works for building Mizar's executables, although most of them don't really have help messages and it's hard to discern the purpose of prune, for example.
Also, for whatever reason, chklab looks for the mml.ini, which is I think is a configuration file for the Mizar Mathematical Library as a whole in the directory where it resides, and you can't pass it flags to make it look somewhere else.
I think the Mizar system as a whole expects to be installed on your machine into a directory like /usr/local or something with a fixed structure and I'm cutting against the grain by trying to use from git repos with strange paths.
Anyway, I am most interested in the commands mizf and miz2prel since I can't find .dpr files corresponding to them, but this Makefile references them.
What are they? And how do you compile them by hand?

There are other scripts, too, which might be relevant/useful. (Plus some OS-specific scripts for Windows/DOS.) I created a pull request and added them alongside the Makefile to the Mizar system git repo.

mizf will verify an article for you.
miz2prel will add an article to your local database for you to use "as if" it were part of the MML.
After all, Mizar is a batch-style proof checker, so these just streamline a couple of common batch jobs. (But you can use them to approximate an interactive proof assistant, which is what happens with the Emacs mizar-mode experience.)
In greater detail, they are shell scripts which perform batch jobs for you. On POSIX machines, they are literally shell scripts. For example, mizf looks like:
#!/bin/sh
#
#          Mizar Verifier, example shell command
#

accommodate()
{
 makeenv $1
 if [ "$?" = "0" ]
  then
   verify $1
  else
   errflag $1
   addfmsg $1 $MIZFILES/mizar
   exit 2
 fi
}

verify()
{
 verifier $1
 errflag $1
 addfmsg $1 $MIZFILES/mizar
}

if [ -z "$1" ]
 then
  echo "> `basename $0` error : Missing parameter"
  echo "Usage: `basename $0` mizar_article_name"
  if [ -n "$MIZFILES" ]
   then
    MizarReleaseNbr=`awk -F= '/MizarReleaseNbr/{print $2}' $MIZFILES/mml.ini`
    MizarVersionNbr=`awk -F= '/MizarVersionNbr/{print $2}' $MIZFILES/mml.ini`
    MizarVariantNbr=`awk -F= '/MizarVariantNbr/{print $2}' $MIZFILES/mml.ini`
    MMLVersion=`awk -F= '/MMLVersion/{print $2}' $MIZFILES/mml.ini`
    NumberOfArticles=`awk -F= '/NumberOfArticles/{print $2}' $MIZFILES/mml.ini`
    echo "MML ver. $MMLVersion.$NumberOfArticles for Mizar ver. $MizarReleaseNbr.$MizarVersionNbr.$MizarVariantNbr available in $MIZFILES"
  fi
  exit 1
 else
  accommodate "`dirname $1`/`basename $1 .miz`"
fi

Similarly, miz2prel adds an article you are writing and have verified to your local MML database. It's also a literal shell script on *nix machines (there's a miz2prel.bat for Windows and DOS machines).
Its contents:
#!/bin/sh
#
#          Mizar local data base creation, example shell command
#

accommodate()
{
 accom $1
 if test "$?" = "0"
  then
   exporting $1
  else
   errflag $1
   addfmsg $1 $MIZFILES/mizar
   exit 2
 fi
}

exporting()
{
 exporter $1
 if test "$?" = "0"
  then
   make_prel $1
  else
   errflag $1
   addfmsg $1 $MIZFILES/mizar
   exit 3
 fi
}

make_prel()
{
 transfer $1
 for ext in dno dcl dco def the sch
 do
  if test -f "$1.$ext"
   then
rm "$1.$ext"
  fi
 done
 echo "Local data base created"
}

if test -z "$1"
 then
  echo "> `basename $0` error : Missing parameter"
  echo "Usage: `basename $0` mizar_article_name"
  exit 1
 else
  accommodate "`dirname $1`/`basename $1 .miz`"
fi

The Windows/DOS .bat files are analogous to these.

There's also a miz2abs script which will create a .abs file corresponding to your .miz file. The .abs file will contain the definitions, registrations, and theorem statements, but omit the proofs. It will also contain comments numbering the theorems and definitions for you.
